# Problems in building Linux kernel modules

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-kernel

I have installed Ubuntu on a VMWare. My purpose is to build kernel modules in it. I am a beginner. I have written a basic module. But I am not able to compile it with the 'Makefile'. What do I need to fix?

Contents of the C file(kernel.c):-

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Contents of the makefile:-

```
obj-m+=kernel.o

all:
 make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=$(shell PWD) modules

clean:
 make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(shell PWD) clean
```

Comment: Please add more code or details what problem are you facing? One thing which I notice in your ***Makefile*** is that there should be space at the beginning of `make` command like 

`all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules`.

Comment: Is it really too hard to post a code that you have to resort to image file? I think it's even harder to give guidance when the asker has not given much effort in the post. And the image you posted will disappear someday. This post will be worthless for future readers.

Comment: @vinodmaverick . I tried the way you suggested. It still has the same problem.

Comment: @vinodmaverick :I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on the Virtual box. Then installed 'vim'. In the home directory I made a new directory and created a Makefile as above and then a file name kernel.c with the above-given contents.

Comment: @alvits: I am really sorry. Made the mistake as I am very new to stackoverflow. I intention is write a basic kernel module and run it.

Comment: @vinodmaverick: When I execute the makefile I get the error as "Makefile:7: *** missing separator. Stop."

Comment: `TAB` (`\t`) is the missing separator. The lines `make -C /lib/modules...` should be indented by a tab, not space.

Answer (score 0):

Make uses TAB as delimiter, not space. Your Makefile should be written as below.

```
obj-m+=kernel.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=${PWD} modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=${PWD} clean
```

It should also be noted that ${PWD} is an environment variable. There is no need to shell out to read an env variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Can't believe I was stuck on a tab for 3 days. Really thanks a lot.